# rtspsrc not working when using protocols=tcp and feeding from a cellphone app

Tags: tcp, udp, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to use my cell phone as an RTSP server and my PC as the client. So for the cell phone, I'm using the RTSP Camera Server android app and on the PC I tried this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=rtsp://IP:Port/camera latency=100 ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

After running this command the output is stuck in "Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request" state without showing any frames:
[image]

If I change the protocols to UDP or delete that argument, then it works:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe rtspsrc protocols=udp location=rtsp://IP:Port/camera latency=100 ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

However, I need it to be TCP since I'm going to use the pipeline inside a docker.
Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your App doesn't support RTSP over TCP. Please try another app like VXG RTSP Server